# Removing Duplicate Values of Arrays Before Inserting into Database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to get values using form array which is

```
<input type="hidden" name="hifiWith[]" value="<?php echo $row['userID']; ?>" />
```

and the other using href

```
<a href="#" class="clickThis" rel="<?php echo $row['userID']; ?>">
 <img src="<?php echo '../uploads/'.$row['userImg']; ?>" /></a>
</a>
```

and submitting this using ajax.everything works fine but i m getting duplicate values as two values are from form and one is from `href` click

and on `insertData.php` accepting it

```
//for href click
 $hifiTo=$_REQUEST['hifiTo'];

//for form array values
$hifiWith=$_REQUEST['hifiWith'];
```

I want to remove the values from array that is in `href`.

I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: is something wrong with my question ?

Comment: Not quite sure if I understand your question. Like a few other people. :)

Comment: I m comparing two people  so user clicks on one of the two image so along with that click userID i want both the userID should be inserted into db

Comment: The one which is click and the one which is not click as well must be inserted into table in column hifiTo and hifiWith respectively

Comment: @Edvin Tenovimas I have edit my question with small keyboards hope it understand now

Comment: I guess you have solved your problem. I didn't have time to look at it, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `insertData.php` file add the following to remove the duplicates

```
//for href click
$hifiTo=$_REQUEST['hifiTo'];

//for form array values
$hifiWith=$_REQUEST['hifiWith'];

// Assuming the $hifiWith is an array, if not do some validation before this step
if(($key = array_search($hifiTo, $hifiWith)) !== false) {
    unset($hifiWith[$key]);
}

// Now your $hifiWith will have the duplicate removed.
....
```